# Definitely install a package in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have to reinstall all the packages like `dplyr`or `ggplot2` each time that I restart Rstudio.

Do you have any suggestion for setting once and for all my packages in Rstudio?

`> version`

> Blockquote               _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          2.2
>   year           2015
>   month          08
>   day            14
>   svn rev        69053
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
>   nickname       Fire Safety
>   Blockquote

Comment: Do you have to really reinstall them? Or does just loading them with e.g. `library(ggplot2)` suffice?

Comment: Yes, I had to reinstall each time. Finally, I created a R.profile file for each project, and I put a R script for automatically installing packages when I load the project.

Answer (score 1):

You could either have a script that runs:

```
packages <- c("plyr", "ftnonpar")
install.packages(packages)
```

Where you would just add entries for each package in `packages`, and run the script each time you open.

However, it might just be that you are not calling the packages each time you restart Rstudio and need to use:

```
library(<package_name>)
```

For each package you intend to use at the top of your script.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Finally, I created a R.profile file for each project, and I put a R script for automatically installing packages when I load the project